# How can I capture return value with Python timeit module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, timeit

Im running several machine learning algorithms with sklearn in a for loop and want to see how long each of them takes.  The problem is I also need to return a value and DONT want to have to run it more than once because each algorithm takes so long. Is there a way to capture the return value 'clf' using python's timeit module or a similar one with a function like this...

```
def RandomForest(train_input, train_output):
    clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
    clf.fit(train_input, train_output)
    return clf
```

when I call the function like this

```
t = Timer(lambda : RandomForest(trainX,trainy))
print t.timeit(number=1)
```

P.S. I also dont want to set a global 'clf' because I might want to do multithreading or multiprocessing later.

Comment: Why do you even use `timeit` if you force `number=1`? `timeit` is useful to automatically handle *repetitive* timing, where you don't know how much time you should run the function to get a good timing etc. In your case simply using `time` would be fine and you wouldn't need any hack to get the return value.

Comment: Can you provide an example link for me to see what you are referring to? I google time and it seems that the module which you might be talking about only seems to involve formatting dates and timezones, etc

Comment: Never heard of [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html#time.time)? Or [`time.clock()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html#time.clock)? The `timeit` module uses these functions to perform the timings. If you only have to do *one* timing you can simply call them directly, in the same way as the `_timer` function is used in unutbu answer (that is actually a reference to `time.time` or `time.clock` depending on the OS).

Comment: @Bakuriu I understood that timeit also does other things, like turn off garbage collection to make sure that we're doing a fair comparison.  i.e., that we're looking at execution time, not wall time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem boils down to [timeit._template_func](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/84f9bf424720/Lib/timeit.py#l80) not returning the function's return value:

```
def _template_func(setup, func):
    """Create a timer function. Used if the "statement" is a callable."""
    def inner(_it, _timer, _func=func):
        setup()
        _t0 = _timer()
        for _i in _it:
            _func()
        _t1 = _timer()
        return _t1 - _t0
    return inner
```

We can bend `timeit` to our will with a bit of monkey-patching:

```
import timeit
import time

def _template_func(setup, func):
    """Create a timer function. Used if the "statement" is a callable."""
    def inner(_it, _timer, _func=func):
        setup()
        _t0 = _timer()
        for _i in _it:
            retval = _func()
        _t1 = _timer()
        return _t1 - _t0, retval
    return inner

timeit._template_func = _template_func

def foo():
    time.sleep(1)
    return 42

t = timeit.Timer(foo)
print(t.timeit(number=1))
```

returns

```
(1.0010340213775635, 42)
```

The first value is the timeit result (in seconds), the second value is the function's return value.

Note that the monkey-patch above only affects the behavior of `timeit` when a *callable* is passed `timeit.Timer`. If you pass a string statement, then you'd have to (similarly) monkey-patch the `timeit.template` string.

Comment: Hmmm,this seems to be returning me the function and not the functions return value.  But what I have to do is capture it with ret_val = t.timeit(number=1)[1]() to actually run the function and get me back the value.  Isnt that running the function twice though?

Comment: Given the code you posted, I don't see why `t.timeit` should be returning a function. Do you get the same result as I do when you run the code I posted? If so, then you need to compare the what's different between that code and your code (paying particular attention to the *type* of the objects passed and returned.)

Comment: You are right I was still using timeit.Timer( lambda: dummy) instead of just timeit.Timer( dummy).  There are some exceptionally smart ppl on StackOverflow. Damn I love this site.

Comment: From looking at the source for timeit; it appears the purpose of the module is for it to be used at the command line as a testing tool for optimization of your code and for Python itself.  If you are writing an app to test something;  say the speed of an API call you may be better of using time.perf_counter twice and doing a subtraction on the two numbers.

Comment: This may have worked, but as of 2023-07-11 it doesn't. The provided code only returns the time taken, as it would normally. The answer by Brendan Cody-Kenny resolves that (although it ain't pretty)

Answer (score 25):

For Python 3.5 you can override the value of [timeit.template](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/timeit.py#l70)

```
timeit.template = """
def inner(_it, _timer{init}):
    {setup}
    _t0 = _timer()
    for _i in _it:
        retval = {stmt}
    _t1 = _timer()
    return _t1 - _t0, retval
"""
```

[unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24812460/771112) works for python 3.4 but not 3.5 as the _template_func function appears to have been removed in 3.5

Answer (score 8):

Funnily enough, I'm also doing machine-learning, and have a similar requirement ;-)

I solved it as follows, by writing a function, that:

- runs your function
- prints the running time, along with the name of your function
- returns the results

Let's say you want to time:

```
clf = RandomForest(train_input, train_output)
```

Then do:

```
clf = time_fn( RandomForest, train_input, train_output )
```

Stdout will show something like:

```
mymodule.RandomForest: 0.421609s
```

Code for time_fn:

```
import time

def time_fn( fn, *args, **kwargs ):
    start = time.clock()
    results = fn( *args, **kwargs )
    end = time.clock()
    fn_name = fn.__module__ + "." + fn.__name__
    print fn_name + ": " + str(end-start) + "s"
    return results
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand it well, after python 3.5 you can define globals at each Timer instance without having to define them in your block of code. I am not sure if it would have the same issues with parallelization.

My approach would be something like:

```
clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
myGlobals = globals()
myGlobals.update({'clf'=clf})
t = Timer(stmt='clf.fit(trainX,trainy)', globals=myGlobals)
print(t.timeit(number=1))
print(clf)
```

Comment: Nice shot, definitely the more elegant solution, it also allows to pass dictionary to `timeit.Timer`. Thank you for sharing

Answer (score 3):

As of 2020, in ipython or jupyter notebook it is

```
t = %timeit -n1 -r1 -o RandomForest(trainX, trainy)
t.best
```

Comment: You're mixing results: The OP wants the result of the timed function `clf` in order to not run this function twice (once to get the result, once to get the time), not the result of the "magic" `timeit` IPython function (which `-o` indeed provides).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to monkey-patch `timeit`, you could try using a global list, as below. This will also work in python 2.7, which doesn't have `globals` argument in `timeit()`:

```
from timeit import timeit
import time

# Function to time - plaigiarised from answer above :-)
def foo():
    time.sleep(1)
    return 42

result = []
print timeit('result.append(foo())', setup='from __main__ import result, foo', number=1)
print result[0]
```

will print the time and then the result.

Answer (score 0):

An approach I'm using it is to "append" the running time to the results of the timed function. So, I write a very simple decorator using the "time" module:

```
def timed(func):
    def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        import time
        s = time.clock()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        e = time.clock()
        return result + (e-s,)
    return func_wrapper
```

And then I use the decorator for the function I want to time.

Answer (score 0):

The original question wanted allowance for multiple results, multithreading, and multiprocessing. For all those, a queue will do the trick.

```
# put the result to the queue inside the function, via globally named qname
def RandomForest(train_input, train_output):
    clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
    clf.fit(train_input, train_output)
    global resultq
    resultq.put(clf)
    return clf

# put the result to the queue inside the function, to a queue parameter
def RandomForest(train_input, train_output,resultq):
    clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
    clf.fit(train_input, train_output)
    resultq.put(clf)
    return clf

# put the result to the queue outside the function
def RandomForest(train_input, train_output):
    clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
    clf.fit(train_input, train_output)
    return clf


#usage:
#     global resultq
#     t=RandomForest(train_input, train_output)
#     resultq.put(t)

# in a timeit usage, add an import for the resultq into the setup.
setup="""
from __main__ import resultq
"""

# # in __main__  # #

#  for multiprocessing and/or mulithreading
import multiprocessing as mp
global resultq=mp.Queue() # The global keyword is unnecessary if in __main__ ' Doesn't hurt

# Alternatively, 

# for multithreading only
import queue
global resultq=queue.Queue() # The global keyword is unnecessary if in __main__ ' Doesn't hurt

#   do processing

# eventually, drain the queue

while not resultq.empty():
  aclf=resultq.get()
  print(aclf)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a callable class that wraps your function, and captures its return value, like that:

```py
class CaptureReturnValue:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.return_value = None

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.return_value = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then call timeit like that:

```py
    crv = CaptureReturnValue(f1)
    elapsed_time = timeit.timeit(lambda: crv(your_parameters), number=1, globals=globals())
    print(crv.return_value)
    print(elapsed_time)
```

Note that the timing overhead is a little larger in this case because of the extra function calls.

Answer (score -1):

For Python 3.X I use this approach:

```
# Redefining default Timer template to make 'timeit' return
#     test's execution timing and the function return value
new_template = """
def inner(_it, _timer{init}):
    {setup}
    _t0 = _timer()
    for _i in _it:
        ret_val = {stmt}
    _t1 = _timer()
    return _t1 - _t0, ret_val
"""
timeit.template = new_template
```