# Python timeit or custom Timer for production

Tags: python, python-2.7, timeit

We are currently using a custom Timer class (sample given below) to compute and log time taken for various pieces of modules in our Tornado app. I was exploring [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#python-interface) module and wonder if we should make use of this instead.

I understand that timeit is used for ad-hoc testing of a piece of code. But, our scenario is we got to log execution time every time a method/ piece of code is called, in our logs.

I also find the following points on timeit limiting blending it in our current app code:

- It expects a string for the function call. That makes it weird to call my function every time as a string, passing it to timeit.
- I don't find any direct method to get return value of the method when I pass the function to timeit. 
  There is a [stack overflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812253/how-can-i-capture-return-value-with-python-timeit-module) for the same. But, it looks more like a workaround and parsing a tuple every time sounds clumsy.

Should I stick with our custom Timer class? 
If not, how to include timeit into the code, without disrupting the code?

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

***Sample Timer Class***

```
import time
class Timer(object):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = time.time()
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.end = time.time()
        self.interval = self.end - self.start
        print self.interval
```

Comment: checkout cProfile https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Comment: I am in this same state but for a different app.

Comment: @shadow0359 Profiling and benchmarking are dealt differently I suppose.